# Passing arguments to Promise Sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a node js plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-sequence, what I am trying to do is to pass arguments to each function when calling pipeline.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var pipeline = require('promise-sequence/lib/pipeline');

var commonFunctions = require('./websites/_common/commonFunctions')

var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true,
  fullscreen : true,
  waitTimeout: 10000
});

  var resultsPromise = pipeline([
    commonFunctions.accessURL(nightmare),
    commonFunctions.loginToWebsite(nightmare),
  ])
  .then(() => commonFunctions.success(nightmare))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

However, when I am trying to pass arguments , it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: tasks[0].apply is not a function
at C:\sad\node_modules\promise-sequence\lib\pipeline.js:25:57
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
```

How can I pass my nightmare variable to each function as an argument in pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either bind those functions:

```
var resultsPromise = pipeline([
  commonFunctions.accessURL.bind(null, nightmare),
  commonFunctions.loginToWebsite.bind(null, nightmare),
])...
```

Or use anonymous functions:

```
var resultsPromise = pipeline([
  function () { return commonFunctions.accessURL(nightmare); }),
  function () { return commonFunctions.loginToWebsite(nightmare); }),
])...
```

Which you can make it shorter using arrow functions if you are using ES6:

```
var resultsPromise = pipeline([
  () => commonFunctions.accessURL(nightmare),
  () => commonFunctions.loginToWebsite(nightmare),
])...
```

The thing to note here is that, pipeline requires array of functions to be passed to it, with these methods, we keep passing functions but `commonFunctions.accessURL` and `commonFunctions.loginToWebsite` will be called with the `nightmare` variable eitherway.

The reason your code doesn't work, or as you say calling them directly, is that when you call your functions, they start executing and they return the promise, but pipeline doesn't expect promises instead it expects functions that returns promises, so it will call those functions whenever they start executing. Bind basically creates new functions that are pre-loaded with the given arguments, which is what we do in the anonymous function case.

Comment: Why, it doesn't work directly? Why there is need of anonymous functions?

Comment: Thank you @Farid.